# Uncaught ReferenceError: keyword is not defined at UseFetch.jsx and at Transactions.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost, vite

I am trying to load a website to my localhost but keep running into an error that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: keyword is not defined at useFetch (:3000/src/hooks/useFetch.jsx:21:7) at TransactionsCard (:3000/src/components/Transactions.jsx:33:18)`. The issue hapens in my code where I'm fetching gifs from my API at giphy developer.

Here is the source code:

Transactions.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants";

export const TransactionContext = React.createContext();

const { ethereum } = window;

const createEthereumContract = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

    return transactionsContract;
};

export const TransactionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [formData, setformData] = useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });
    const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem("transactionCount"));
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = (e, name) => {
        setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
    };

    const getAllTransactions = async () => {
        try {
            if (ethereum) {
                const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();

                const availableTransactions = await transactionsContract.getAllTransactions();

                const structuredTransactions = availableTransactions.map((transaction) => ({
                    addressTo: transaction.receiver,
                    addressFrom: transaction.sender,
                    timestamp: new Date(transaction.timestamp.toNumber() * 1000).toLocaleString(),
                    message: transaction.message,
                    keyword: transaction.keyword,
                    amount: parseInt(transaction.amount._hex) / (10 ** 18)
                }));

                console.log(structuredTransactions);

                setTransactions(structuredTransactions);
            } else {
                console.log("Ethereum is not present");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const checkIfWalletIsConnect = async () => {
        try {
            if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask.");

            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });

            if (accounts.length) {
                setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);

                getAllTransactions();
            } else {
                console.log("No accounts found");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const checkIfTransactionsExists = async () => {
        try {
            if (ethereum) {
                const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();
                const currentTransactionCount = await transactionsContract.getTransactionCount();

                window.localStorage.setItem("transactionCount", currentTransactionCount);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);

            throw new Error("No ethereum object");
        }
    };

    const connectWallet = async () => {
        try {
            if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask.");

            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts", });

            setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
            window.location.reload();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);

            throw new Error("No ethereum object");
        }
    };

    const sendTransaction = async () => {
        try {
            if (ethereum) {
                const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
                const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();
                const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);

                await ethereum.request({
                    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
                    params: [{
                        from: currentAccount,
                        to: addressTo,
                        gas: "0x5208", //21,000 gwei in hexadecimal form
                        value: parsedAmount._hex,
                    }],
                });

                const transactionHash = await transactionsContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);

                setIsLoading(true);
                console.log(`Loading - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
                await transactionHash.wait();
                console.log(`Success - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
                setIsLoading(false);

                const transactionsCount = await transactionsContract.getTransactionCount();

                setTransactionCount(transactionsCount.toNumber());
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                console.log("No ethereum object");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);

            throw new Error("No ethereum object");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfWalletIsConnect();
        checkIfTransactionsExists();
    }, [transactionCount]);

    return (
        <TransactionContext.Provider
            value={{
                transactionCount,
                connectWallet,
                transactions,
                currentAccount,
                isLoading,
                sendTransaction,
                handleChange,
                formData,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </TransactionContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

useFetch.jsx:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_GIPHY_API;

const useFetch = () => {
    const [gifUrl, setGifUrl] = useState("");

    const fetchGifs = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${API_KEY}&q=${keyword.split(" ").join("")}&limit=1`)
            const { data } = await response.json();

            setGifUrl(data[0]?.images?.downsized_medium?.url)

        } catch (error) {
            setGifUrl('https://metro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/pokemon_crying.gif?quality=90&strip=all&zoom=1&resize=500%2C284')
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (keyword) fetchGifs();
    }, [keyword]);

    return gifUrl;
}

export default useFetch;
```

When I comment out the lines that use 'keyword' it launches with no errors. This is at lines 14, 18, and 58-62 of Transactions.jsx.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have not define keyword inside your useFetch function.

If you are trying to pass the keyword from the place where you use useFetch then do something like below and use the useFetch like `const gifUrl = useFetch(<keyword>)`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_GIPHY_API;

const useFetch = (keyword) => {
    const [gifUrl, setGifUrl] = useState("");

    const fetchGifs = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${API_KEY}&q=${keyword.split(" ").join("")}&limit=1`)
            const { data } = await response.json();

            setGifUrl(data[0]?.images?.downsized_medium?.url)

        } catch (error) {
            setGifUrl('https://metro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/pokemon_crying.gif?quality=90&strip=all&zoom=1&resize=500%2C284')
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (keyword) fetchGifs();
    }, [keyword]);

    return gifUrl;
}

export default useFetch;
```

or even try adding default value for key work like below.

```
const useFetch = (keyword = "some keyword") => {
```